# react-native-contact API getAll not working

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, error-handling, react-native-contacts

I have a problem running the react-native-contact package with the `getAll` API, with messages:

```
Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.
```

```
[[49,22],[4,0],[[248,2000,1683564057640,false]],8807]
Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.
```

How do I solve it?